# Importing from Excel or a CSV file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to import data to a sql table finding a row by column A  and putting column B and C into the row into specific data columns.

My excel/CSV file is similar to:

```
Code,Unit,Price
1234,Pack10,1.20
4567,Each,3.40
```

My table is similar to

```
ItemID Code Name ItemPrice Unit Supplier LastCost SellBy QtyStock Inactive
```

I need to update the table from the lines in the spreadsheet finding the code row and replacing the Unit and the ItemPrice columns.

I have tried using the standard import data but cannot see how to find the code and then insert the required fields.

Any help or point me to where I can find an answer will be most appreciated.

Comment: In Windows you can create an ODBC data source and query the excel sheet as if it were a table in a database. If you create a linked data source in SQL Sever you can use the results as the source for a insert into select.

Answer (score 0):

Breakup the problem into two smaller steps...  First, do just the standard import data, and place the contents of your excel file into a SQL table.  After you've imported the data, perform just a standard SQL update statement to join together your imported table and your existing table to update the existing table.

```
UPDATE e
SET
    Unit = i.Unit,
    ItemPrice = i.Price
FROM
    ExistingTable e JOIN
    ImportedTable i ON i.Code = e.Code
```

Comment: I need to do this frequently to update units and prices to existing codes, so would prefer a single import option if its possible to bring straight from the file to the table.

Comment: The import data feature is about inserting records (import), not updating, so you have to split the problems as mentioned by @mfredrickson

Answer (score 0):

To make it in a single step you can use `OPENROWSET` as follows:

```
UPDATE A
   SET [ItemPrice] = B.Price,
       [Unit] = b.Unit
FROM   [SO].[dbo].[PricesTbl] A INNER JOIN
       OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
       'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Prices.xls', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]') B ON A.CODE=B.CODE
```